# Can I use OS X Notes app from 10.9+ on 10.8

Tags: macos, notes.app

I recently read a question which explained that the ability to search Notes was introduced in OSX 10.9 and above.  Earlier versions will show you which note a search query exists in but will not search the note itself.

My question is:

Can I use a newer version of notes from 10.9 or 10.10 on OS X 10.8?  I'd like this extended functionality but do not want to upgrade my entire OS just for this one feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use versions of applications designed for (or included with) a later version of OS X on a prior version.